# CSS combination of :after and :hover:after on multiple HTML tags not behaving correctly

Tags: css, hover, sprite, less, pseudo-element

I am currently running into a problem when trying to implement a simple rollover using CSS :after and :hover pseudo-elements.

Have a look at the clock and facebook icons to the right: http://clean.philippchristoph.de/

Here's the CSS code:

```
.icon {
    background: url('../img/clock_icon.png') top left no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

.icon:after {
    .transition(opacity, .2s, ease);

    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px; left: 5px; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    background: url('../img/clock_icon.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: -25px 0;
    opacity: 0;
}

.icon:hover:after, .clock:hover div {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

As you can see, the image is faded using a sprite and opacity. However, now I can't seem to hover both elements anymore. As you will see on the example page, you can hover over the facebook icon, but not over the clock. If you remove the facebook icon, you can hover over the clock again. Note that the two icons are entirely seperate elements.

I've tested this behavior on both FF and Chrome on Windows.

It'd be awesome if someone could shed some light onto this issue.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your CSS with this one (I mean the mentioned classes only, not your entire CSS :) ):

```
.icon {
     background: url("../img/clock_icon.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
     height: 25px;
     width: 25px;
     position: relative
}

.icon:after {
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
     background: url("../img/clock_icon.png") no-repeat scroll -25px 0pt transparent;
     bottom: 0pt;
     content: " ";
     left: 0;
     opacity: 0;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0pt;
     top: 0;
}

.icon:hover:after, .clock:hover div {
     opacity: 1;
}

.facebook, .facebook:after {
     background-image: url("../img/facebook_icon.png");
}

.clock {
    position: relative
}

.clock div {
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
     color: #A0A0A0;
     font-size: 12px;
     left: 40px;
     line-height: 11px;
     opacity: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 5px;
     width: 160px
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D Adding "position: relative;" to ".icon" fixed the whole issue..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: relative` to your `icon` class, so that the generated content is positioned relative to that, rather than the parent. I've tried to simplify what you have [in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RNLP/), though I wasn't 100% sure what you are after. Is that close? I also amended the positioning of the generated content.

It's worth noting that - annoyingly - you can't apply a transition to generated content (which is why any attempt to have the opacity transition on these elements will fail in your case). Hopefully this will change soon.